# Ce n'est pas là

Tags: sens, démonstratifs

> Ce n'est pas là un métier honnête.

Quelle est la signification de cette phrase ?

Comment: "This here is not an honest job" would be my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to say which part of a sentence confuses you :p Guessing, like Con-gras-tue-les-chiens, that it's *là* ...

This *là* is demonstrative in origin, used to indicate "this here" or "that one there", which is where Aerovistae's translation comes into play. It suggests the speaker either looking at or actively discussing a particular métier, and then issuing this opinion. We could be passing by a stock brokerage or something, both glance up at the sign, and you say the sentence you quoted.

Also, demonstratives imply a focus and the focus implies an exclusion of other things. So say I'm talking about honest métiers with you. You jokingly suggest the profession of pickpocket. I could reply with the sentence you quoted, meaning, "No, not *that* one. Back to the ones I meant!"

That function of focus has, over time, generalized so that *là* doesn't necessarily need an obvious referent but can just mean "here, now, whatever is happening", as in [the Collins entry](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/l%C3%A0):

> **Non, là, je ne vois vraiment pas ce qu'on peut faire.** No, I really can't see what we can do about this.
>
> **Là il exagère!** Now he's really going too far!

This is probably the sense intended since the more narrowly demonstrative sense would tend to be expressed as « ce métier-là ».

Comment: The following reference (TLFi) might be found a truer explanation of the relations involved: B emploi référentiel,  [Particule de renforcement d'un dém., avec le gallicisme de présentation, de mise en relief c'est, ce sont] Ce sont là des erreurs impardonnables; c'est là le fond du problème, la difficulté. J'ai toujours aimé la bonne chère (c'est là mon moindre défaut)

Comment: You mean the link on "TLFi"? Or is it something else?

Comment: @user168676 You had just posted the incomplete draft but now it's good. Merci.